# could not found detail of the product using REST API

Tags: magento-2.1, product, rest-api

I tried to get all the product using REST API,i used this url 
"http://localhost/magento2.1/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[pageSize]=100&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1"

Output of this url:

```
"item" : {
        "id" : 13,
        "sku" : "play game",
        "name" : "play game",
        "attribute_set_id" : 4,
        "price" : 59,
        "status" : 1,
        "visibility" : 4,
        "type_id" : "simple",
        "created_at" : "2018-05-10 11:59:37",
        "updated_at" : "2018-05-10 11:59:37",
        "weight" : 3,
        "extension_attributes" : [ ],
        "product_links" : [ ],
        "tier_prices" : [ ],
        "custom_attributes" : [
            {
                "attribute_code" : "description",
                "value" : "<p>high quality chip ,rom:4gb.</p>"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "meta_title",
                "value" : "play game"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "meta_keyword",
                "value" : "play game"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "meta_description",
                "value" : "play game high quality chip ,rom:4gb."
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "news_from_date",
                "value" : "2018-05-01 00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "news_to_date",
                "value" : "2018-05-31 00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "options_container",
                "value" : "container2"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "required_options",
                "value" : "0"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "has_options",
                "value" : "0"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "country_of_manufacture",
                "value" : "JP"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "url_key",
                "value" : "play-game"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "tax_class_id",
                "value" : "2"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code" : "gift_message_available",
                "value" : "2"
            }
        ]
    },

In this output it does not given detail of this field
"extension_attributes" : [ ],
"product_links" : [ ],
"tier_prices" : [ ],
```

How can i get the detail of this field.
can u provide the url or give detail so that i can get the detail of this field  in rest api .

Answer (score 0):

To fetch complete product detail, you can use product detail API.

http://localhost/magento2.1/rest/all/V1/products/{{sku}}

Comment: Its will provide single product detail with SKU, but i need to get all the product detail in one API call.

Comment: May be you need to create a new custom API for this

Comment: Thanks Yash Patadia, I want all product detail with single api call but not single product with SKU.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get all product details, you need to pass like this.but it will take time to load all the products.

http://localhost/magento2.1/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria

Comment: thanks Vishnunath,   its provides all product but its is given detail of this feilds extension_attribute,product_links and tier_prices. The output is "extension_attributes:[ ],"products_links:[ ], and "tier_prices":[ ]. I want all the details that are inside extension_attributes,product_links and tier_prices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all product details, you need to pass searchCriteria parameter in REST Api

http://yourdomain.com/V1/products/?searchCriteria[pageSize]=2&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1